# Angular 7: Disable and Enable particular form field in angular 7 reactive form

Tags: angular

I know questions like this has been asked before but unfortunately those didn't work out for me.
So I am working in `angular 7` I created a reactive form field that contain firstname, lastname and some other details and every field is disabled by default and also have their own edit button.

**So what I want is to enable and disable the particular field for which I click the edit button rest other fields should remain disabled.**

May be I should create my own custom directive but that's really confusing for me.

So is there any easy way to achieve this? or if custom directive is the only easy way to achieve this then please help out with some link or code to do this.

Right now I created a variable of boolean type and by using this variable I enable and disable it, but problem with this approach is I have to created separate variable for each field in order to avoid confusion but I don't think that is count under the best approach. I shared my code for better understanding.

**component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

profileForm: FormGroup;
userData: User
isDisable :boolean = true
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user data"));

    this.profileForm = new FormGroup({
      'firstname': new FormControl({value: this.userData.firstname, disabled: this.isDisable}, Validators.required),
      'lastname': new FormControl({value: this.userData.lastname, disabled: this.isDisable}, Validators.required)
    })
  }

  onEdit(value:string) {
    this.isDisable=!this.isDisable
    console.log(this.isDisable);

    if(!this.isDisable) {
      this.profileForm.controls[value].enable()
    }
    if(this.isDisable) {
      this.profileForm.controls[value].disable()
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.profileForm.value)
  }

}
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="form-section">
    <form
    class="login-form"
    [formGroup]="profileForm"
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <div class="row mb-4 no-gutters">
          <div class="col-4 property">
              First Name:
            </div>
            <div class="col-7 value">
              <div class="form-group m-0">
                <input 
                type="text" 
                class="form-control" 
                name="firstname"
                formControlName="firstname" 
                id="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 value">
              <button 
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary"
              (click)="onEdit('firstname')">
                  edit
              </button>
            </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row mb-4 no-gutters">
          <div class="col-4 property">
              Last Name:
            </div>
            <div class="col-7 value">
              <div class="form-group m-0">
                <input 
                type="text" 
                class="form-control" 
                name="lastname"
                formControlName="lastname" 
                id="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1 value">
              <button 
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary"
              (click)="onEdit('lastname')">
                  edit
              </button>
            </div>
      </div>
      <button 
      class="btn btn-primary mt-4"
      [disabled]="!profileForm.dirty"
      type="submit">Submmit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you could do instead of passing control name in `onEdit('firstname')` method you can pass control itself and check if its disabled then enable it and vice versa.

in template

```
(click)="onEdit(profileForm.get('firstname'))" <== pass control itself
```

in component

```
onEdit(control: AbstractControl) {
  control.status === 'DISABLED' ? control.enable() : control.disable();
}
```

Comment: It worked but when I made any changes and again disable the field my submit button also gets disabled, or even if I don't disable the field after making any changes and submit the form field it only console the value of the field which is update and not the other, can you help me with this ?

Comment: @AyushVerma when you want to disable and enable button means on what criteria button should enable disable?

Comment: @AyushVerma technically submit button should only disable when form is invalid, what you did `[disabled]="!profileForm.dirty"` means only disable when form fields not touched or modified which is not a good approach. Try `[disabled]="profileForm.invalid"`

Comment: I can work with that but can you please tell me how to console all the form value even if it is not changed.

Comment: @AyushVerma inside your submit method you can `console.log(this.profileForm.value)` to print all form values.

Comment: I am doing that only, still only showing the value that I have edited.

Comment: @AyushVerma in submit method before console.log add `this.profileForm.enable()`